# Wordrpess: Issues in CSS animations in Mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-animations, elementor

In my `Elementor Pro` powered website, I have added custom CSS for animating the `Shape Divider`. I have the "Brush Wave" style as the shape divider. Below is the code

```
 .elementor-shape-bottom

 .elementor-shape-top

 .elementor-shape



body {
     overflow-x:hidden;
} 

@keyframes wave {
   0% {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
     50% {
     margin-left: -1600px;
   }
   100% {

     margin-left: 0px;
   }
 }  
   .elementor-shape-top {
     bottom: -1px;
     animation: wave 22s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
     width: 210%;
 } 

 .elementor-shape-bottom {
     bottom: -1px;
     animation: wave 22s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
     width: 210%;
 } 

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .elementor-shape-top {
     bottom: -5px;
     animation: wave 22s cubic-bezier(  0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
     width: 210%;
 } 

 .elementor-shape-bottom {
     bottom: -5px;
     animation: wave 22s cubic-bezier(  0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
     width: 210%;
 } 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {

}
```

This works fine in Desktop, but in tablets and mobile it is not. The animation is working, but it overlaps with the other sections. The top animation overlaps with the its top section while the bottom animation overlaps with its bottom section.

Check below for an example. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Use responsive media queries to set different dimensions for your animation and also try to use margin in percentage, it help you a lot.

Comment: @Awais: Any example?

Comment: Can you provide us code-pen or fiddle of your complete code?

Comment: Please provide the html and css both code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the separate media query for mobile devices
@media only screen and (min-width: 240px) and (max-width: 480px)  {..Your code here..}

and also please use 'em' for width instead of '%'  as you have used -> width: 210%;

Thanks may be it helps you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer following the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and adjust the typesetting.

Comment: you mean max width 480 and min width 240??

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is body overflow-x doesn't work on mobile and tablet

Try to use a div include your content

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="elementor-shape-bottom"></div>
        <div class="elementor-shape-top"></div>
        <div class="elementor-shape"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```